# Facebook comments plugin language

Tags: facebook, comments

I got this problem:

When i set `Facebook JavaScript SDK` to:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/cs_CZ/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=675698015778617";
```

...for CZECH language javascript shows error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (http://connect.facebook.net/cs_CZ/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=675698015778617:42`

But when I set language to `en_GB` everything works just fine.

What is wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: If that specific language version causes errors right now, file a bug report with Facebook.

Comment: How can i do that? thnx

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs – start typing into search field; if no matching bugs are found use the “create new bug report” option at the bottom.